# Session Cookie, auto logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-cookies

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 for a site I am making. It has a login that leads to some backend sites. That all works fine...
BUT...
There seems to be a logout thing in the Session cookie. Whenever I login and leave it for a few minutes it logs me out when I load the page.

Does anybody know what I can do to change this... or remove it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to set your session timeout on your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="10"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: is the timeout = "10" in minutes??

Comment: yes, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**Default value for session timeout is 20 minutes.** You can change it in your webconfig as per your need.